# Creating a Bitbucket-Repository in Java via REST

Tags: java, rest, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to create a Bitbucket repository using their REST-API. Everything seems to work except setting the "parent" project, where the repository needs to be created in. On [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#post) link a cURL example is provided. In the body, the parameter "scm" is set as either "git" or "hg", both being Strings, the parameter "project" seems to be a json object containing a key-value pair. Everything I tried so far did not work (json object, string, etc.)

Question: How can I create a repository IN a specific project?

My code looks the following:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/" + tName + "/" + rName;
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Basic 1234567890qwert");
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

MultiValueMap<String, String> project = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
project.add("key", "aaaaaaaa"); //the repo should be created in the project aaaaaaaa

MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
postParameters.add("scm", "hg"); //hg or git, does not matter
postParameters.add("project", project); //<-- the api ignores the declared project

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(body, headers);

ResponseEntity<BitbucketRepository> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, BitbucketRepository.class);

System.out.println("createRepository: " + response);
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [bitbucket-rest](https://github.com/cdancy/bitbucket-rest) library to do this like so:

```
BitbucketClient client = BitbucketClient.builder()
.endPoint("http://127.0.0.1:7990")
.credentials("admin:password") // will base64 for you if not already done. Can optionally use token auth as well.
.build();

CreateRepository crepo = CreateRepository.create("my-repo", true);
Repository repo = client.api().repositoryApi().create("my-project", crepo);
```